# angular cli proxy conf not working?

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular CLI (ng4) and within my proxy configuration I am declared the rest api call which is outside my application.

After ng build --prod --aot=true I am getting status code 404. In development modus it is working. What can I do to solve this problem?

**My app.ts file**

```
if (app.get("env") === "development") {

    app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../src/assets')));
    // app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../src/pages')));

    app.use(function(err, req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.json({
            error: err,
            message: err.message
        });
    });
}

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  // in production mode run application from dist folder
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../client')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ng build and deploy the built file to your HTTP server, the proxy configuration is completely irrelevant.

The proxy configuration can be used with `ng serve`, so that the development server started by `ng serve` acts as a proxy for (typically) REST api requests targeting another backend server.

Read [the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md).

Comment: I see, but how can I fix it? Otherwise I am not able to call a rest api which is running outside. Should I write then the full path like http://localhost:4200/rest/api? instead of /rest/api

Comment: How are you deploying your angular app? Where is your backend located, and what is serving your frontend?

Comment: my node.js is running on port 3000 and angular on port 4200. the webserver name is www.djangoxx:4200.  I hope this helps?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You said you used ng build. ng build just buids the application and generates its files in the dist directory. Now you need to start an http server to serve those files. How do you do that? What is running on port 4200 to serve these files? Why aren't these files served by the node.js server running on port 3000?

Comment: Angular CLI is running on port 4200. Node.js is running on port 3000 and I call it also over the proxy-conf with localhost:3000. Please look above in the app.ts file how I serve those file in dev and prod modus